# What's the English transliteration of this Sanskrit mantra?

Tags: sanskrit

Can someone please give me the English transliteration of this Sanskrit mantra? How do you say it in English?

[image]

Comment: Mantras with beejas must be received from a guru - a proper guru; not the modern-day pseudo gurus. And not everyone is eligible to receive them.

Comment: There are Sanskrit [transliteration tools](http://www.learnsanskrit.org/tools/sanscript) online. You may use them.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Mantra is montra, why does it matter whether we receive it from a guru or from internet? If we chant any mantra then we will surely gets benefit of it, doesn't matter what's the source of occupation.

Comment: See this [meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/2995). Also try https://www.ashtangayoga.info/sanskrit/transliteration/transliteration-tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Om Hreem dharaNendra paarshvanaathaaya namah nidhi darshanam kuru-kuru svaahaa

This is the English transliteration of the above mantra.

However, it looks like Jain mantra.

P.S: There are many variants of Parshvanatha and its consort Sri PadmAvati. It can be found in various agamas (jaina).

Comment: It's indeed a Jain mantra, how did you know?

Comment: @MahaRex Cos Parshvanatha and Padmavati are powerful Jain deities. I have some acquaintance with jina and bauddha mantras.

Comment: I'm a Hindu, predominantly a Vaishnava, and a vegetarian who does not eat any onions and garlic, do you think it's ok for me to chant this mantra? Even though I'm Hindu, I always consider myself to also be a Jain and Buddhist, because all of our religions are the Dharmic religions.

Comment: @MahaRex these are general mantras for wealth and prosperity. There is no strict rules for initiation in this. You can try them if you wish.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, Mantras must be [learned from a Guru](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16992/3500) or from knowledgeable saints only, especially the one with *[Bheejas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19445/3500)*.

The mantra you have given is:

> ॐ ह्रीं  धरणेन्द्रः पाश्र्वनाथाय नमः निधि दर्शनं कुरु-कुरु स्वाहा ।
>   (Devanagari)

Its transliteration in IAST and ITRANS:

> oṃ hrīṃ dharaṇendraḥ pāśrvanāthāya namaḥ nidhi darśanaṃ kuru-kuru svāhā । (IAST)
>   OM hrIM dharaNendraH pAshrvanAthAya namaH nidhi darshanaM kuru-kuru svAhA | (ITRANS)

Read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17653/3500) for more details on structure of Mantras.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, where I live (New York City) there isn't any Gurus or Swamis, at least authentic ones, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @MahaRex But don't chant Mantra on your own. It is very dangerous. You should know proper intonation and you can only know that from learned person. There can be negative consequences if you do so. Instead, you can chant name of Gods like "Rama"  If possible, you can visit any Hindu Ashrama or temples near New York and learn mantra from Swamis there..

Comment: I do know a Jain temple in Queens, I might pay them a visit. I got this mantra from a Tantric text. It has to be chanted for 125,000 times in order to gain siddhi, but since the solar eclipse is coming soon on 8/21/2017, I hope that by chanting it during the eclipse, I can gain siddhi over it quickly, since, supposedly, chanting a mantra once during a eclipse is equal to chanting it one thousand times. Again, thank you for your answer and wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

Devanagari Mantra:

> **ॐ ह्रीं धरणेन्द्रः पाश्र्वनाथाय नमः निधि दर्शनं कुरु-कुरु स्वाहा**

Google Translation to English:

> om hreen dharanendrah paashrvanaathaay namah nidhi darshanan kuru-kuru
>   svaaha

By using following site http://spokensanskrit.de/training/transliteration.php you can translate like below:

[image]