# Beeja mantra meaning

Tags: mantras

I searched a lot regarding meanings of beeja mantras (esp. klim, sauhu, aim, hrim, shrim). Web gives overall meaning. e.g. 'aim' is saraswati mantra; may the goddess Saraswati bless you'; 'Hrim' is tantrik pranav and yogik hrudaya. That's it. And the same case for other beej mantras.

Request if I can get thorough explanations with scripture references for these beeja mantras.

Comment: Related or duplicate of [What are the beeja mantras and what is their significance in meditation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19445/5212). Explanation of these mantras in the answers is not recommended because they are too many and these should be learnt properly from a guru. If they're not chanted properly, it is fruitless or negative.

Comment: hmmm..... That's right. I agree. Moderator may delete this question.

Comment: Nowadays recordings of many manthras are available.

Comment: Yeah. Many of those recordings mess-up with pronunciations. e.g. Gayatri Mantra record. It is not to be chanted in this fasion loudly.

Comment: Bija mantras have to be pronounced correctly and need to be imparted from your guru. Remember that all is vibration, and sound is a vibration. The vibration of power in a bija mantra comes from the vibration being imparted from the guru to the disciple. Mantras pronounced incorrectly can lead to opposite results. You - your jiva, and your body -  are at a certain vibration. The bija imparted by the guru is the one that best 'tuned' for your vibration. If you think you know or can learn on your own, it is only your ego talking.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda there is no harm in knowing the meanings of the beejamantras. Any initiated brahmin can do pujas of all deities (and trantric pujas can be done by nonbrahmins also). and there he has to do japa of the beejamantra of that deity. So if he knows the meaning of the beejamantra, thatsvdesirable.

Answer (score 4):

Here are meanings of some beejamantras:

Beejamantra of Maa Kali: क्रीँ = क् + र् + ई + चन्दविन्दु. क् implies काली, र् implies Brahma,ई implies Mahamaya,चन्द्रविन्दु chandra implies Naada and bindu implies dukkhaharana. So the meaning of the mantra is: [May] Naaada and Brahmamoyi Mahamaya Kali remove my sorrows and sufferings and give me bliss. This is according to the Mantrarthaavidhana of the Varadatantra.(page 65):

"क काली ब्रह्म र प्रोक्तं महामायार्थकश्च ई। विश्वमात्रर्थको नादो विन्दुर्दुःखार्तिहारकः॥तेनैव कालिकादेवीं पूजयेद् दुःखशान्तये॥"

In the sanketatantra, we get:

ककाराद्विश्वमुत्पन्नं तेन सृष्टिस्वरूपिणी।
रेफः कालाग्निरुद्रात्मा तेन संहाररूपिणी।
ईकारश्च महालक्ष्मीर्लोकत्रयविभाविनी।
तेनेयं पालिनी शक्तिः सामरस्यं च विन्दुना॥ (Ref : Purascharyarnava, page 724)

The above means the Devi Kali is Goddess of creation, destruction and preservation of the three worlds and one with Shiva.

According to the Todalatantra,  क् means dharma, ई means artha, र् means kama and anuswara means moksha. Here the beeja is mentioned as क्रीँ. So the meaning becomes that Goddess Kali is bestower of Dharma, Artha, Kama and Moksha.(Ref: Shasramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das, Vol 1, page 466).

The beeja mantra of Sri Krishna is  क्लीं.Here क् means Krishna, ल् means Aishwarya, ई means Santosha and anuswara means give bliss and remove dukkha. So the mantra means: [May] Krisna, the Lord of all wealth make me blissful and remove my sorrows.

The beeja mantra of Devi Durga is ह्रों. ह् means Shiva, र् means Prakiti, ई means Mahamaya and anuswara means remove sorrows and give bliss. So the mantra means: [May] Devi Mahamaya Durga who is the wife of Shiva remove my suffering and give me bliss. (Ref: Omkarnatha-Rachanavali, page 113).

Normally in non-yuktakshara mantras like ऐं,  which is the mantra of Guru, Saraswati and Kundalini, the first letter denotes the deity and the anuswara has the meaning mentioned above.

Hope this answers your question.

**UPDATE**

The beeja mantra of Shiva is हौं. ह् means Shiva, औ means Sadashiva, Vindu means :Remove suffering. So the meaning is

> May Lord Shiva, the Ever-Doer of Good, remve my suffering.
>
> shiva-vAchi ha-kAras tu aukArah syAd sadAshivah/ sunyam dukkha-harArtham tu tasmAt tena shivam yajet.//(Reference: Ahnik-Kritya, Shyamacharan Kaviratna VidyAvAridhi, Vol.1, page 79).

Similarly there are meanings of other veeja mantras in the 6th patala of the VaradA-Tantra.

Mantrarthavidhan also I think would be a basic text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whether there is any url for "Purascharyarnava" scripture?

Comment: just now found it here https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.487362/page/n47

Comment: pl let me know if you can find verse number / reference for Sauhu beej and other beejas

Comment: Also, this url https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.290166 for Shastramulak Bharatiya Shakti Sadhana   but I can't read it because it is written in BAnglA language. Surely you can.

Comment: I hv already upvoted the answer but usually DUM is considered Durga Bijam ... it is the Ekakshara Durga Mantra .. Hrim is called Maya/Shakti or Bhuvana bija .. but overall correct ... bcoz we hv Om  hrim dum durgayai namaha @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: @Rickross DUM is the beeja mantra of Jagaddhatri Durga and used in jagaddhatri puja. Hrim is used in Durga Puja.Regards

Comment: @Rickross Hreem is actually called Maya beja, maya meaning shakti or durga

Comment: But where did u find that? tantrasara gives Dum as the Durga mantra just like Gam is for Ganesha @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: @Rickross pujapaddhati books

Comment: Btw Hrim is also known as Shakti Pasa Bija, Am Shiva Pasa Bija, Krom both's Ankusha Bija ... and Tham is Shakti Dhanur Bija etc ..:D @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: @Rickross yes.thts why in dkshna kali mntra hreem is used 4 times along with kreem where the mula mantra is kreem